# How to return a value within a promise in angular 2

Tags: angular, promise, angular2-services, angular-promise, session-storage

I want to check sessionStorage (sessionStorage['new']) for a value and if it exists, I want to return it and disregard the rest of the function, but I get an error that then is not defined. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
public getDispositionTree(memberType: string,
                          market: string,
                          includeFiltered: boolean = false,
                          forcedUUIDS: string[] = [],
                          includeArchived: boolean = false): 
    Promise<DispositionTreeNode[]> {

    let treeLoadedPromise;

    if (this.savedDispositionTrees.has(market)) {
        treeLoadedPromise = Promise.resolve();
    } else {
        // **THIS LINE BELOW IS MY CHANGE**
        treeLoadedPromise = sessionStorage['new']
        // treeLoadedPromise = this.loadDispositionTree(market);
    }
    return treeLoadedPromise.then(() => {
        if (includeFiltered) {
            if (includeArchived) {
                return this.savedDispositionTrees.get(market);
            } else {
                return this.getExcludeArchivedDispositionTree(this.savedDispositionTrees.get(market));
            }

        }
        return this.getRelevantDispositionTree(market, memberType, forcedUUIDS);
    });
}
```

This is the error:

```
 core.es5.js?0445:1085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: 
 treeLoadedPromise.then is not a function
 TypeError: treeLoadedPromise.then is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error doesn't state that `then` is not defined.

You are setting `treeLoadedPromise` to whatever is returned from `sessionStorage["new"]`.  This value isn't going to be a promise.  If the item is present, this will return a string, otherwise it will be `undefined`.

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
let treeLoadedPromise;

if (this.savedDispositionTrees.has(market)) {
    treeLoadedPromise = Promise.resolve();
} else {

    let sessionStorageValue = sessionStorage['new'];
    if (sessionStorageValue !== undefined)
    {
        treeLoadedPromise = Promise.resolve(sessionStorageValue);
    }
    else
    {
        treeLoadedPromise = this.loadDispositionTree(market);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Do I leave the rest of the code underneath as is?

Comment: `Promise.resolve(value)` will return a Promise that is resolved to value.  Because it's now a promise instead of a string, you can call `then()` on it.  I've had to read through the docs a few times to understand promises.  In particular, try [this page.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

Comment: Ah, so the promise needs to be "thenable"? And we can do that by wrapping the session ob in Promise.resolve(sessionObj).

Comment: Yes, the initial problem you were having is that you weren't returning a Promise at all, just a string.  Using `sessionStorage` is going to remove any metadata from an object.  When you try to get it out of local storage it doesn't have any information about being a promise.